# Handling click events for many elements by bubbling

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, events, dom-events

I have a list of controls contained in a parent div called `overlay-controls`.

There is many list controls that each have their own `overlay-controls`.

I am using a for loop to add the event listener to each button that contains the class `delete`.

Before the user can delete the item, they must confirm. I am trying to attach this to every delete button found in overlay-controls.

I got it to work using a for loop but I know there is a better way using bubbling and capturing. I am having trouble targeting only the delete class inside overlay-controls by bubbling up to parent div.

See the live demo here by clicking on each delete button:  http://jsfiddle.net/8qqfeoa2/1/

Here is my code using the for loop:

```
 (function() {
        function getConfirmation(e){
            var retVal = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this request?");
            if( retVal == true ){
               return true;
            }else{
               e.preventDefault();
               return false;
            }
         }

        var del = document.querySelectorAll('.delete');

        for(var i = 0, len = del.length; i < len; i++){
        del[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            getConfirmation(e);
        }, false);
        }

    }());
```

Comment: You tagged the question as jQuery but seem to be avoiding the use of it completely. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: would like to avoid jQuery, (for learning purposes) but will consider a jQuery solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont event need the For / .each loop

Jquery takes care of it internally

`$('.delete').on('click', function(e){
    getConfirmation(e);
});`

Provided you are using jQuery and in getConfirmation method you may also get that specific (clicked) element by using **e.target** which returns the target on which click happened.

Comment: this works would love to see a javascript only solution, didn't need to change my method getConfirmation(e) because we are already targeting the delete button.

Comment: So here you go

`var deletebuttons = document.getElementsByClassName('delete');
for(var button in deletebuttons) {
    button.onclick = getConfirmation;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Only Javascript solution

As you requested one

`var deletebuttons = document.getElementsByClassName('delete');
for(var button in deletebuttons) {
    button.onclick = getConfirmation;
}`